# How to show list characters with red color?

Tags: vimrc, color

I have set `listchar` in `.vimrc` as below:

```
set list  lcs=tab:→\ ,space:·,nbsp:␣,eol:¶
```

How can I display these characters `→\` , `·` , `␣` , `¶` with red color?
Here is my failed attempt:

```
hi! set list  lcs=tab:→\ ,space:·bsp:␣,eol:¶   ctermbg=red  guibg=red
```

Comment: `:h hl-SpecialKey`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do this in two steps. You got the first one right by setting `list` and `listchars`.

The problem comes when you apply the highlight: you cannot combine the commands the way you are trying to.

As Matt pointed in his comment, the highlight group responsible for `listchars` characters is `SpecialKey`.

```
" Enable
set list
set listchars=tab:→\ ,space:·,nbsp:␣,eol:¶


" Highlight
highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=blue ctermbg=red guifg=blue guibg=red
```

As you can see, I separated the settings in several lines and expanded them to their long name for more clarity, which is arguably more appropriate if you want to put these lines in a `vimrc`.